# Cloudformation CF Script for Windows not copying files from s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

New to AWS. I created below CF Template to copy java.exe in my s3 bucket to Windows and install it. However, I dont see the executable copied over in the first place. Can someone guide me on what's the issue here?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: >-
  Cloud Formation template snippet to install Java JDK on Windows
  Server 2012 R2. (c) 2017 Air11 Technology LLC -- licensed under the Apache
  OpenSource 2.0 license, https://opensource.org/licenses/Apache-2.0
Metadata: {}
Parameters: {}
Rules: {}
Mappings: {}
Resources:
  JavaSeleniumEC2Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      KeyName: 'windowskeypair'
      ImageId: ami-0093d2a4365944361
      InstanceType: 't2.micro'
      IamInstanceProfile: <Existing IAM Role which has EC2 Full access to S3>
    Metadata:
      'AWS::CloudFormation::Init':
          config:
            files:
              c:\\jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe:
                source: "https://<mybucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe"
              c:\\Install-Java-JDK.ps1:
                content: !Join
                  - ''
                  - - 'Set-Location C:\\;'
                    - '.\\jdk-11.0.9_windows-x64_bin.exe /s'

            commands:
              command: >-
                    powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command c:\\Install-Java-JDK.ps1
                    waitAfterCompletion: '60'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AWS::CloudFormation::Init` does not execute by itself. You have to **explicitly execute** it in your `UserData` using `cfn-init.exe`. One example of doing this is shown [here](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-templates-us-east-1/Windows_Single_Server_SharePoint_Foundation.template). You would have to locate more on how to do it exactly on Windows.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I added the UserData, but still same issue exists. Will post that as a separate issue